# How do I fix missing Filed "id" error from Google? missing data

Tags: breadcrumbs, structured-data

I use Structured Data on my site including breadcrumbs.  I received multiple warning emails from Google Webmadter tools stating the following errors were found:

Missing Filed "id"

Missing Filed "position"

On review of the structured data, both tags are present.  Has anyone encountered these errors and, if so, what was your resolution?

Comment: I'm facing the issue also after google announce news on Sep 19, 2019 https://twitter.com/googlewmc/status/1174693878835875840 right now google webmaster tool show Missing Filed "position" but no error on Googles Structured data testing tool

Comment: @PanupongKongarn  I altered this to show a question and the answer, please take a look at the answer, use the structured testing tool, my guess is that you have a markup issue like I had.

Comment: No error on Googles Structured data testing tool but If you look at Google Web Master Tool you will see the error.

Comment: Can you paste your structured data code, I will take a look and see if I can help.

Comment: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?utm_campaign=devsite&utm_medium=microdata&utm_source=breadcrumb#url=https%3A%2F%2Fgrandcondom.com%2F%E0%B8%96%E0%B8%B8%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%A2-100-%E0%B8%8A%E0%B8%B4%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%99-%E0%B8%94%E0%B8%B9%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%95%E0%B9%8C-%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%9F%E0%B8%B5%E0%B9%88-52-%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%A1-dumont-comfy
Thank you.

Comment: When reviewing the link, your issues are related to missing / incorrect tags.  The menu to the right specifies where your errors are in the structured data.  These are generic markup mistakes, not errors relating to the change of the tags I mentioned.  Follow the guides on the menu, they provide examples of how the structured data tags need to be populated for your product.

Comment: I didn't see any breadcrumb error in the structured data

Answer (score 0):

An initial visual check of the structured data suggested all markup was correct.

I then double checked using Googles Structured data testing tool https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool, this flagged odd errors.

The error is generated due to old markup code.  The structured data needs to be updated.  Specifically, in for these errors:

Change the "property" tag to "itemprop"
This resolved the errors for me: https://us.icalculator.info/salary-comparison-calculator/south-dakota.html

I thought I would share as I know many will wake up to those notifications and, like me, panic.  I actually noticed a drop in traffic in relation to this so there are likely SEO components that suggest a quick fix is necessary, I hope it helps.

for info, I use Microdata:

```
<ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
     <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses">
    <span itemprop="name">Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses/real">
    <span itemprop="name">Real Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
 </li>
</ol>
```

See the structure here: https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList

I dont claim to be an expert on Structured data, in fact I believe this should be automated by the search engines really, its just another layer of code that slows sites.  Anyway, I put as a question so that those with more knowledge etc can expand on the info as needed.  I have split this to a separate question and answer as suggested.